# Implementing jquery multiselect on web2py user sign up page

Tags: jquery, web2py

Could someone tell me how I can get the `jquery.multiselect.js` working on the `db.auth_user` table/ default/user/register page.

I got this far, but don't know how to edit the html page / controller to get it working

```
auth.settings.extra_fields['auth_user']= [
    Field('affiliation'),
    Field('job_title'),
    Field('access_request', 'list:string', requires=IS_NOT_EMPTY(), comment = 'Please select your reason/s for requesting access to the database '),
    Field('country', 'reference country')]
auth.define_tables(username=False, signature=False)


db.auth_user.access_request.requires = IS_IN_SET(('VecTraits - download data','VecTraits - submit data','VecDyn - download data','VecDyn - submit data'),  multiple=True)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

actually found an easier solution, just adding a web2py widget did it

```
    Field('access_request', 'list:string', multiple=True, widget=SQLFORM.widgets.checkboxes.widget),
```